# How to log what node Selenium Grid tests are running on

Tags: c#, logging, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am curious if there is a way for me to log which node my Selenium Grid tests ran on. I am interested in this for debugging purposes. Sometimes I need to look at the `selenium_node` logs and currently I do not know what node the test case ran on that I am interested in. Thus I have to search through each log file on each node. This is really cumbersome and hope I can log the node each test case runs on to speed this process up.

Answer (score 1):

Very recently I built a Java library that lets you interact with the Grid and get the following information programatically. I call it ["Talk2Grid"](https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/talk2grid).

- Given a valid driver session, it lets you figure out to which node was your test routed to.
- From the above api you would get to know the node ip and address. Using this information you can get more details about the node configuration.
- Given the Hub ip and port, you can get more details about the hub configuration.

Talk2Grid is a Maven project and is published to maven central.

You can get started with using it by merely adding the below as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.rationaleemotions</groupId>
    <artifactId>talk2grid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```